# How do I set a fixed scale on y-axis?

Tags: plotting

I wrote a simple example to show the pattern of a stationary wave, using codes as following:

```
Manipulate[Plot[a Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {a, 0, 1}]
```

However, when I'm running it, the scale of $y$-axis is changing as parameter `a`  is changing. What I want is a fixed $y$-axis range from -1 to 1. What can I do?

P.S. I've tried 'AspectRatio', and it didn't really worked...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `PlotRange`.

Answer (score 3):

As Kuba said in comments, the `PlotRange` option does  what you want:

```
Manipulate[ 
 Plot[a Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], 
 {a, 0, 1}
]
```

Comment: Exactly what I want!  tks.